# mediaelementjs - video player false controls

Tags: javascript, video

Here is the image I'm getting when I add .png files for mediaelementjs player controls, SVG don't work. Why I'm getting this?

http://postimg.org/image/r4buap6zn/

Here is some CSS code used for

```
.mejs-container .mejs-controls {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(mediajselement/background.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(50,50,50,0.7)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.7)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(50,50,50,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(50,50,50,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(50,50,50,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(50,50,50,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));  
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(50,50,50,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));   
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
.mejs-container .mejs-controls  div {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: url(mediajselement/controls.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    border: 0;
}

.mejs-controls .mejs-button button {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 7px 5px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent url(mediajselement/controls.svg);
}

.no-svg .mejs-controls .mejs-button button { 
    background-image: url(mediajselement/controls.png);
}
```

also this didn't help, .htaccess -

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```

or this

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svg
```

BY this point I have controls.png, and controls.svg in every directory I could set, I have tried every location. THIS is mindblowing.

somethings really wrong cause I'm using this player on other syte with exact configuration and it works like that, it's just a shame people have to go trought this :)

Comment: Can your browser see the controls at http://mediaelementjs.com? Do you have a test URL you can show?

Comment: Yes, my browser can see it there and following url - http://skatetunes.sytes.net/uploaded.php?link=39 I already use this configuration there.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/76qcek0pl/ this shows that I see svg in browser.  I set <script src="/js/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/template_faili/mediaelementplayer.css" /> in header, + I have those files there. + it works on that page.

Comment: background: url(bigplay.svg) no-repeat; works, when I set controls.svg it doesn't, it must conspiracy

Comment: I'm confused. I see the controls here: http://skatetunes.sytes.net/uploaded.php?link=39. Where are the controls not working for you?

Comment: controls are not working here http://84.237.249.24:82/

Comment: hafl controls on firefox, none on chrome http://postimg.org/image/jhs6hc29l/bcb6fd92/

Comment: I'm off with your player, sucks to have no controls, so default it goes, sorry for asking help. Good luck with your opensource project - my mother crys for not having money, and me sitting here killing time :>

Comment: This page 84.237.249.24:82 doesn't seem to have an opening `<html>` tag or references to any JavaScript libraries.

Comment: Thats bad argument. I did it 9 hours, do you think I couldn't check for once if controls work on the skateshop.sytes.net? I must be blind to miss the point what ELSE I could miss on <head tags>. Those must be magic libraries that doesn't allow multiple page instances again.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Had a quick look at mejs source css, you'd probably need these [styles](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/master/build/mediaelementplayer.css#L220-L231)

I could be missing the point here as im not massively familiar with svg, i think background-image properties look a bit odd,

try below

```
.mejs-container .mejs-controls  div {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-image: url(mediajselement/controls.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    border: 0;
}

.mejs-controls .mejs-button button {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 7px 5px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border: 0;
    background-image: url(mediajselement/controls.svg);
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: that made controls up the window, and no buttons at all

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/xp66rhtax/ with these lines background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: so, good news it is not repeating anymore. Now you probably need correct backgroud position values. Refer to mejs website and maybe do a quick inspect on the player controls to see various ```backgroun-position``` values. Or even better, check out the css the came along with the plugin

Comment: what do I have to refer? I already have exact same player working, I made same configuration, 3 hours for setting a video wrapper is kinda bad feeling, I try png, svg and none of it works like on the other page.. and I don't just know why - here's refer to that awfully hard to set wrapper http://mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: Updated my answer pointing out additional styles from the plugin css that are necessary

Comment: Why svg then doesn't answer at all, but png does?

Comment: Try accessing svg file directly via browser url bar - if it works, that means there is something wrong the css setup. if it doesnt work, that means path could be incorrect or server isnt configured properly

Comment: it does exist just like .png, how else I could see png then?